# document.getElementById("xxx").style

Tags: javascript, css

I want to use getElementById("xxx").style.color = "xxx".
With this I want to change some css value.  But the problem is when i use this and test all same id with this but it does't effect all id and effects only the first one.

Sample code is as follow:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id = "test">Test</div>
<div id = "test">Test</div>
<div id = "test">Test</div>
<div id = "test">Test</div>
<script>
     document.getElementById("test").style.color = "blue"
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What should i do to change all 4 Test to color blue.
AnyIdea pls.
Thanks

Comment: You can only have 1 instance of an ID on a page.

Comment: Ok i got it bro,
I'm just beginner that's why i don't even know the difference of id and class.

Comment: Why dont you want to use jQuery here ? it is more easy then pure javascript while just setting css on that elements

Comment: @Kirankumar seeing he only just started html/js coding i guess he doesn't know jQuery

Comment: This works http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30777829#30777829

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An ID **must be unique** in an HTML document. Write [valid HTML](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

To represent multiple, related elements: **use a class**.

You can then use `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelectorAll` to get an array-like object which you can use a `for` loop to access each element in turn.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".test");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].style.color = "blue";
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Test</div>
<div class="test">Test</div>
<div class="test">Test</div>
<div class="test">Test</div>
```

Alternatively, write a stylesheet with a descendant combinator and toggle the classes on a containing element.

```js
document.getElementById("container").classList.add("foo");
```

```css
.test { color: black; }
.foo .test { color: blue; }
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="test">Test</div>
  <div class="test">Test</div>
  <div class="test">Test</div>
  <div class="test">Test</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, an ID must be unique. If you want to give multiple DOM-elements the same style just use 'class'.
you could try this:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="test">Test</div>
  <div class="test">Test</div>
  <div class="test">Test</div>
  <div class="test">Test</div>
  <script>
    var divList = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
    for (var i = 0; i < divList.length; i++) {
      divList[i].style.color = "red";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

to change the style using javascript.

Comment: The name `divArray` is misleading. It isn't an array.

Comment: Good point, changed the name to `divList`

Comment: @ThomasS If you edit a variable name, please ensure that it gets reflected to the whole code. I still see `divArray` instead of `divList` :-)

Comment: @KarelG sorry I was just editing it to make it a snippet ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code :

- `id` must be unique, so you should use eg. `class` instead
- you should loop across the different elements that are selected

This is my prefered way to correct those two problems :

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="test">Test</div>
    <div class="test">Test</div>
    <div class="test">Test</div>
    <div class="test">Test</div>
    <script>
        Array.prototype.slice.call(
            document.getElementsByClassName("test")
        ).forEach(function(element) {
            element.style.color = "blue"
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c7ph5q2c/1/).

Answer (score -2):

**For jQuery Solution**

You cannot use same id for performing same operation on all the elements

You can use class name and add style using jquery like

```
 $(".className").css("color","blue");
```